# Accessing private String defined in IApplication implementaion in another class

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, rcp

In our RCP application, We have Application.java class which implements IApplication. In this Application.java class, I have introduced a new string variable which will be assigned with the values that are passed in from commandline to start the exe. This commandline instruction tells me that which perspective and view to load when the application starts and I want to use this information in another class which extends WorkbenchWindowAdvisor. Is there a way for me to access the String variable inside Application.java inside the other class?

I am looking at any method under PlatformUI.getWorkbench() which would let me access the instance of Application.java

Any help is Appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any way to get the `IApplication`.

You can get the command line arguments anywhere by calling `Platform.getCommandLineArgs()` so perhaps you should do the command line processing outside of the application class (that is `org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform` - there are several Platform classes in Eclipse).